# How to see why a long-running AWS Step Function failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have an AWS Step Function with many state transitions that can run for a half hour or more.

There are only a few states, and the application loops through them until it runs out of items to process.

I have a run that failed after about half an hour. I can look at the logging under the "Execution event history". However, since this logs every transition and state, there are thousands of events. I cannot page down to show enough events (clicking the "Load More" button) without hanging my browser window.

There is no way to sort or filter this list that I can see.

How can I find the cause of the failure? Is there a way to export the Execution event history somewhere? Or send it to CloudWatch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the AWS CLI command [`aws stepfunctions get-execution-history`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/stepfunctions/get-execution-history.html) with the `--reverse-order` flag in order to get the logs from the most recent (where the errors will be) first.

Answer (score 0):

How do you process your steps? Docker containers on ECS or Fargate? Give us some details on that.

Your tasks should be sending out logs to CloudWatch as they execute.
You can also look at the Docker logs themselves on the physical machine if your run docker on a machine you can SSH to.

Comment: The steps are each very simple: either looking up to see if there are any more entries in a DynamoDB table, or triggering one or more Lambdas to execute. The Lambdas themselves logs to CloudWatch, but I found no errors in their logs.
My issue is that I can't even see where the failure happened. The run is listed as "Failed" but I can find no output because I can't access the tail of the Execution event history.